# R - Add New Column Based On Partial String Match From Another Column

Tags: r, tidyverse

I'm trying to find out a way in tidyverse or via regular R to create a new column when a portion of the next matches. Desired result for my dataframe. Example: In row one "FB + IG" was used in campaign name, therefore, newColumn value is "FB + IG"

| id | Campaign name | New Column |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 001 new campaign - FB + IG - Dec | FB + IG |
| 2 | 002 nov campaign - BO123- FB - Nov | FB |
| 3 | 003 - IG - Sep | IG |

Thx

Answer (score 0):

We can use `sub` from `base R` to do this

```
df1$NewColumn <- trimws(sub(".*-\\s*(.*)\\s*-.*", "\\1", df1$`Campaign name`))
```

-output

```
df1
#  id                      Campaign name NewColumn
#1  1   001 new campaign - FB + IG - Dec   FB + IG
#2  2 002 nov campaign - BO123- FB - Nov        FB
#3  3                     003 - IG - Sep        IG
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(id = 1:3,
    `Campaign name` = c("001 new campaign - FB + IG - Dec", 
  "002 nov campaign - BO123- FB - Nov", "003 - IG - Sep")),
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
 -3L))
```

Comment: sorry, i should have added that that the delimiter may/may not be in the exact place and therefore, string search might be required. I've updated the example above.

Comment: @AdilK same code should work on that.  I updated the example

Answer (score 0):

Using regex lookarounds:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% mutate(newcol = str_extract(`Campaign name`, '(?<=-\\s).*(?=\\s-)'))
# A tibble: 3 x 3
     id `Campaign name`     newcol 
  <dbl> <chr>               <chr>  
1     1 001 - FB + IG - Dec FB + IG
2     2 002 - FB - Nov      FB     
3     3 003 - IG - Sep      IG
```

Data used:

```
df
# A tibble: 3 x 2
     id `Campaign name`    
  <dbl> <chr>              
1     1 001 - FB + IG - Dec
2     2 002 - FB - Nov     
3     3 003 - IG - Sep
```

Comment: sorry, i should have added that that the delimiter may/may not be in the exact place and therefore, string search might be required. I've updated the example above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use positive lookbehind `(?<=-\\s)` and positive lookahead `(?=\\s-)`as well as the negated character class `[^-]+`, which prevents the `-` character from getting included in the extraction:

```
df1$New <- str_extract(df1$`Campaign name`, "(?<=-\\s)[^-]+(?=\\s-)")
```